# If I were you, I wouldn't bother him while he ..... sleeping.- "is" vs "was"

Tags: conditional-constructions, tense-agreement

This is a second conditional

> If I were you, I wouldn't bother him while he --------- sleeping.

What goes in the blank space?

---

*My opinion: I've seen people use the present tense and past tense ( maybe it was the past subjunctive)*

Comment: It’s ***is***.  To use *was* it’d have to be:  “If it had been me, I wouldn’t have bothered him while he was sleeping.”

Comment: Picture you and a friend standing above a sleeping man.  You’re about to poke him, but your friend grabs your hand and says ***~***.  *Was* doesn’t fit there.

Comment: I think there are two grammatical options: *is or will be*, because this conditional can refer to present or future events.

Comment: @LucianSava You mean it could be "while he will be sleeping.."? Hmm.. It's pretty uncommon to use "will" in a subordinate clause (though it's possible in some appropriate contexts).

Comment: @LucianSava - Unfortunately that’s not correct.  That construction seems to be prevalent in Indian English, but to any native speaker it sounds wrong.  “*will be sleeping* indicates that in the future he’s going to be sleeping.

Comment: I'm a native speaker and I would use **was**, though I can't explain why. I just know that conditional/subjunctive tenses are weird in English.

Comment: Never mind my above comment. I figured out it's a mistake related to "were", since "were" is usually past tense, but subjunctive in this context.

Answer (score 1):

Both "is" and "was" are correct. The reason has to do with the fact that past tenses can be used to indicate either a time that has gone by or an impossibility. That can lead to ambiguity, leaving the speaker with a choice between choosing consistent tenses or resolving the ambiguity. In this sentence, the speaker is putting him- or herself into an impossible situation (being someone else). This version:

```
If I were you, I wouldn't bother him while he was sleeping.
```

chooses to keep the tenses consistent. The speaker is consistently imagining a world where he or she was the other person, and is focusing (subconsciously) on the unreality of that world. By contrast, in this version:

```
If I were you, I wouldn't bother him while he is sleeping.
```

the speaker wants to emphasize the fact that the sleep is ongoing. He or she might have said:

```
My opinion is that you should not bother him while he is sleeping.
```

In writing, I would generally choose the first option, especially if you can provide enough context to reduce ambiguity. However, I think the second option is not wrong, even in writing. I am a native speaker, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

I asked this same question in another forum and this the only answer I got . Apparently this person is a native speaker.

"For the past tense, I would probably use "when" in place of "while":
If I were you, I wouldn't bother him when he was sleeping.

Please don't ask me to justify those choices. "
*  Yes, It kind of looks like wandrea's answer. 
I'd like someone​(preferaly a native speaker) to tell which option is correct  and if there more than one option. whats the difference between those sentences in which each option is used .

Comment: "While" seems more pedantically correct, but I don't think it would be inappropriate or awkward to use "when" here.  (I am a native speaker of Canadian English.)

Answer (score -2):

In this case, "is" goes in the blank space. For "was", the sentence needed to have been "If I had been you, I wouldn't have bothered him while he was sleeping"